grammar of a dependent claim
Dependent claim 1:
The method of claim 1, wherein a winner additionally satisfying a second condition of being alive.

Dependent claim 2:
The method of claim 1, wherein a winner additionally satisfies a second condition of being alive.

I know that Dependent claim 2 is grammatically correct.
But I am not sure if Dependent claim 1 is grammatically correct or not.

You appear to asking about whether to use the simple present tense (satisifies) or use participle construction (satisfying).
The simple answer is that you can use both, but the simple present tense (satisifies) should be used if introduded by "wherein". If there is no "wherein", participle construction (satisfying) should be used.
The participle construction turns the sentence into an adjectival phrase (a phrase describing a noun).
Regarding your examples "Dependent claim 1" and "Dependent claim 2",
Dependent claim 2 is grammatically correct.
Dependent claim 1, as it is, is grammatically incorrect.
You can either:

delete "wherein"
"The method of claim 1, a winner additionally satisfying a second condition of being alive", or you can

treat "a winner additionally satisfying a second condition of being alive" as a subject and add a conjugate.



The version labeled claim 1 is not correct English but the second one is correct English.

Do you mean that Dependent claim 1 is worded invalidly and is not correct English?
